# How to conditionally return multiple different columns in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, case

I am trying to return multiple columns only if a condition matches, else, return something else. Using Sqlite3, my understanding is that the way to do this is using CASE, so something like this:

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM disk_encryption WHERE user_uuid IS NOT "" AND vault_status = 'on' LIMIT 1) then "Passing" else "Failing" 
END AS Status,
'Encryption Enabled' AS Policy;
```

This all works great, it returns the following:

```
Status   | Policy
------------------------------
Passing  | Encryption Enabled
```

Now, I am trying to return contextual data if `Status = 'Failing'`.

For example, if `Status = 'Failing'`, I would like to return the `Policy` and `Status` columns, as well as the output of:

```
SELECT name, type, vault_status FROM disk_encryption;
```

How would I do this?

Here is simplified test data I am working with:

```sql
CREATE TABLE disk_encryption(`name` TEXT, `type` TEXT, `user_uuid` TEXT, `vault_status` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (`name`)) WITHOUT ROWID;

INSERT INTO disk_encryption
VALUES ('/dev/disk1s1', 'APFS Encryption', '504', 'on');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of colums in the result cannot be altered within the query depending on the results of the query.
What you can do is adding a third column (eg. Info) which will be empty when status='Passing' and populated when status='Failing'.

Content of the Info column can be a concatenation of values from the subquery.

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM disk_encryption WHERE user_uuid IS NOT "" AND vault_status = 'on' LIMIT 1) then "Passing" else "Failing" 
END AS Status,
'Encryption Enabled' AS Policy,
CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM disk_encryption WHERE user_uuid IS NOT "" AND vault_status = 'on' LIMIT 1)
  THEN ''
  ELSE (SELECT name ||'-'|| type ||'-'|| vault_status FROM disk_encryption)
END AS Info;


Status |Policy            |Info
-----------------------------------------------------------
Failing|Encryption Enabled|/dev/disk1s2-APFS Encryption-off
```

Comment: This is great! I was playing around with CTEs, but this is much simpler.